# alsa does not recognized audio card

Tags: 20.04, sound, alsa, acer, soundcard

I am struggling since days to get Ubuntu to recognize my audio card. It looks like the hardware is detected (Intel C230 on motherboard), but can not get it working. My laptop is a Acer V5-591. I have "dummy output" as hardware. I run Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.8.0-50-generic.

I have tried alsa and oss4.

Based on the diagnotic steps (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) , it looks like alsa is not recognizing with audio card. Here is the output of alsa-info.

Cheers
Marc

```
bash alsa-info.sh --stdout
cat: /proc/asound/version: No such file or directory
alsa-info.sh: line 466: /proc/asound/modules: No such file or directory
cat: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory
cat: /tmp/alsa-info.elfwUt3z79/alsamodules.tmp: No such file or directory
cat: /proc/asound/modules: No such file or directory
alsa-info.sh: line 661: tree: command not found
alsactl: save_state:1595: No soundcards found...
cat: /tmp/alsa-info.elfwUt3z79/alsactl.tmp: No such file or directory
upload=true&script=true&cardinfo=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.5.0
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Sun Apr 18 09:02:49 UTC 2021

!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS \n \l DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS" HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy" UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer: Acer
Product Name: Aspire V5-591G
Product Version: V1.15
Firmware Version: V1.15
System SKU: Aspire V5-591G_1033_1.15
Board Vendor: Acer
Board Name: Usopp_SLS

!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/10251032:00/status 15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status 15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ELAN0501:00/status 15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status 15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/LNXVIDEO:00/status 15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/MSFT0101:00/status 15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status 15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:00/status 3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:03/status 15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:04/status 3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C04:00/status 31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0A:00/status 31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status 9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status 9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status 9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status 9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status 9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status 9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status 9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status 9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:37/status 15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:72/status 11

!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release: 5.8.0-50-generic
Operating System: GNU/Linux
Architecture: x86_64
Processor: x86_64
SMP Enabled: Yes

!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:
Library version: 1.2.2
Utilities version: 1.2.2

!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes

!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [8086:a170] (rev 31)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller [1025:1033]

!!Modprobe options (Sound related)
!!--------------------------------

snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_atiixp_modem: index=-2
snd_intel8x0m: index=-2
snd_via82xx_modem: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_usb_caiaq: index=-2
snd_usb_ua101: index=-2
snd_usb_us122l: index=-2
snd_usb_usx2y: index=-2
snd_cmipci: mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
snd_pcsp: index=-2
snd_usb_audio: index=-2
snd_intel_dspcfg: dsp_driver=1
snd_hda_intel: index=1

!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------

!!Sysfs card info
!!---------------

!!Card: /sys/class/sound/card*
Driver:
Tree:

!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------

crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 1 Apr 18 10:53 /dev/snd/seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Apr 18 10:53 /dev/snd/timer

!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

ARECORD

arecord: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

!!Amixer output
!!-------------

!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
--endcollapse--

!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

acer_wmi
acpi_pad
aesni_intel
af_alg
ahci
algif_hash
algif_skcipher
ath
ath10k_core
ath10k_pci
autofs4
bluetooth
bnep
btbcm
btintel
btrtl
btusb
ccm
cec
cfg80211
cmac
coretemp
crc32_pclmul
crct10dif_pclmul
cryptd
crypto_simd
drm
drm_kms_helper
ecc
ecdh_generic
ee1004
efi_pstore
fb_sys_fops
ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper
hid
hid_generic
hid_multitouch
i2c_algo_bit
i2c_hid
i2c_i801
i2c_smbus
i915
idma64
input_leds
intel_cstate
intel_lpss
intel_lpss_pci
intel_pch_thermal
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_wmi_thunderbolt
ip_tables
joydev
kvm
kvm_intel
libahci
libarc4
lp
mac80211
mac_hid
mc
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
memstick
mxm_wmi
nls_iso8859_1
nouveau
parport
parport_pc
ppdev
r8169
rapl
rc_core
realtek
rfcomm
rtsx_usb
rtsx_usb_ms
rtsx_usb_sdmmc
sch_fq_codel
serio_raw
sparse_keymap
syscopyarea
sysfillrect
sysimgblt
ttm
usbhid
uvcvideo
video
videobuf2_common
videobuf2_memops
videobuf2_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc
videodev
virt_dma
wmi
wmi_bmof
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
x_tables
xhci_pci
xhci_pci_renesas

!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[ 0.126608] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[ 0.126609] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[ 0.126610] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
--
[ 0.239069] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0xfff80000-0xffffffff pref]
[ 0.239084] pci 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[ 0.250563] pci 0000:00:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01-06]
--
[ 17.958919] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 19.410947] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[ 19.532227] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 619444 [ IBUS ]

!!Packages installed
!!--------------------

ii alsa-topology-conf 1.2.2-1 all ALSA topology configuration files
ii alsa-ucm-conf 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.6 all ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii alsa-utils 1.2.2-1ubuntu2 amd64 Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
```